# How to set multiple HTTP headers in JavaScript get () method

Tags: javascript, http, get, header, request

I have been searching the total Internet from around a week and finally decided to post here. I want to send an HTTP get request to an API with two headers for authentication. These are custom headers and need to be sent at once.

I have tried the following code but it never gives me success. The API returns a JSON file which will have parameters like "title", "description". The URL and headers work fine, when I tried it using hurl.it.

This is the code. Please suggest some answer to solve this problem. And one more thing is, I want to do it using JavaScript only, no jQuery, AJAX, or AngularJS.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://affiliate-  api.flipkart.net/affiliate/offers/v1/dotd/json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        function display(arr) {
            var i;
            var out = " ";    
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {  
                out += "<p>title:" + arr.dotd[i].title + "<br>description:" + arr.dotd[i].description + "<br></p>"; 
            }
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = out;
        } 
    }
    else {
        alert(xmlhttp.status);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-  Token","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Id","xxxxxxxxx");
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: The spaces in `Fk-Affiliate-    Token` are probably wrong. Is that in your real code or a copying error? The same thing with the spaces in the URL.

Comment: Possibly API doesn't support CORS. Check for CORS error in  browser dev tools console. Use  proxy if this is the case. Inspect actual request in dev tools network and see if headers are correct also

Comment: the spaces are copying errors.sorry for that.can you tell me how to set multiple headers?

Comment: i came into web development just 15days ago.if API does not support CORS(i know nothing about it),how  hurl.it is getting the JSON file from the server?sorry i'm little confused.this is the error i found using chrome developer console    " XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/offers/v1/dotd/json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://justforfree.in' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."

Comment: This error means, you cannot make an AJAX call from your page to the API, if the API is not on the same host as your page. To prevent this, you can use CORS. The API has then a list of allowed devices and if your host is in this list (e.g. `http://localhost`), Chrome will allow you this API call. This is a security issue to prevent automatic AJAX calls from an evil site to e.g. your e-banking site (the cookies are also passed, and the evil site has access to your e-banking account).

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestions.finally i figured it out.the problem is with API.the API is not supporting CORS pre-flight requests.as the API is of flipkart's,i can not change it.now i have 2 options.
1)using a proxy on my web server to forward requests.
2)using PHP for total development as PHP runs on server,it works.
but i want to know is there any way to bypass CORS using java scipt?